# How to fix the "LazyInitializationException" I'm encountering?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, lazy-loading, marshalling

Hope you'll be able to help me stop hitting my head against a wall.

Here's my problem, after plenty days of research on many forums, I didn't found any compatible answer with the problem I'm encountering.

I have the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.User.pictures, no session or session was closed` that seems to be a known Exception, but still drives me crazy...

I've tried to force Eager loading instead of lazy loading but still having the same issue.

Here are my classes:

category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
public class Category{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String Name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
private Collection<Picture> pictures;

(getters and setters)
```

user.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String username;

private String password;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String phoneNumber;

private String postalAddress;

private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private Collection<Picture> pictures;
   
    (getters and setters)
```

picture.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "picture")
@XmlRootElement
public class Picture {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

private String description;

@Column(columnDefinition="longblob")
private byte[] image;

private Date dateOfPublish;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User author;

    (getters and setters)
```

And here is an example of how I try to retrieve my pictures in database (which is the only one that have foreign keys)

```
@Override
public List<Picture> getAllPictures() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery<Picture> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder()
            .createQuery(Picture.class);
        criteriaQuery.from(Picture.class);
        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Finally called like this:

```
@Path("/picture")
public class PictureController {

@GET
@Path("/all") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Picture> getAllPictures(){
    return DaoFactory.getPictureDao().getAllPictures();
}
```

Full stacktrace of exception below:

févr. 03, 2019 4:38:48 PM org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

GRAVE: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.User.pictures, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.User.pictures, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:578)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:479)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

févr. 03, 2019 4:38:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jersey-servlet a généré une exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.User.pictures, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:272)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:266)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:681)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:345)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:578)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:479)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:145)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractListElementProvider.java:264)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: When you write that you tried to force eager loading, do you mean you changed the `OneToMany` collection called `pictures` to eager? What happened?

Comment: can you tell us which line of code gives you this error?

Comment: I also tried to force eager loading on the OneToMany collection but it tells my that it will produce an infinite file.

Comment: The exception that is throw don't tells me wich line of code summon it. Do you want the entire exception ?

Comment: Can you provide the code which results in this exception ? You are getting this exception on performing some function call right ? Try to provide details of those function

Comment: I think that it is the last sample of code that throw the error

Comment: can you provide the whole stacktrace of exception ?

Comment: It's done (it's a bit long)

Comment: Are you using jersey based web services which calls the getAllPictures method ? Can you show me the part of the code which calls this getAllPictures method ?

Comment: Yes of course, I update it btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let divide this step by step

1) Your jersey web controller is calling your dao method to get list of pictures (No error)

2) Now your dao layer is getting data from database (No error)

3) Value is returned to your web service controller method (No error)

4) But you are using automatic json converter to convert object data to json. Your pictures has data associated with user. When json converter tries to get data of user the value is null because your transaction has already ended which is resulting in exception. Try ignoring category and user fields during json conversion as shown below.

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User author;
```

5) You should not use the picture object directly for json conversion as it will result in cyclic redundancy (infinite loop). Try to create another wrapper class of picture to handle this scenario

Picture -> User -> Picture -> User (Cyclic redundancy)

So for fixing this create three wrapper classes

```
public class PictureWrapper 
{
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private byte[] image;

    private Date dateOfPublish;

    private CategoryWrapper category;

    private UserWrapper author;
}


public class UserWrapper
{
    private int id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String postalAddress;

    private String email;
}

public class CategoryWrapper
{
    private int id;

    private String Name;
}
```

Then change getAllPictures method to following

```
public List<PictureWrapper> getAllPictures() 
{
    List<PictureWrapper> resultList = new ArrayList<PictureWrapper>();
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try 
    {
        CriteriaQuery<Picture> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Picture.class);
        criteriaQuery.from(Picture.class);
        List<Picture> list =  em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    if(list != null && list.size() != 0)
    {
        for(Picture picture : list)
        {
            PictureWrapper pictureWrapper = new PictureWrapper();
            //Load data from picture to picture wrapper with user and category
            resultList.add(pictureWrapper);
        }
    }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        em.close();
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: This solution is interesting but firstly, I don't have the @JsonIgnore annotation. And I want my user and category when I retrieve my pictures, so I don't want to ignore them in the json returned.

Comment: First try commenting the objects part and try. If it works let me know. Then I will suggest you another solution

Comment: I also installed jackson-annotation in order to try your solution but it throws me an
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PU] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: Oooook ! I thank you a million times sir. It works now, I never thought I would have to do a thing like that for this.

Answer (score 1):

- It seems there is no session opened, or no transaction. Your are missing the start and the end of the transaction.
- There are two options, either your manager yourself the transaction either some Transaction Manager does that in some container.
- Non-managed environment idiom

  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   EntityTransaction tx = null;
  try {
      tx = em.getTransaction();
      **tx.begin();**

  // do some work
      ...
      enter code here
      **tx.commit();**
  }
  catch (RuntimeException e) {
      if ( tx != null && tx.isActive() ) **tx.rollback()**;
      throw e; // or display error message
  }
  finally {
      em.close();
  }
- more info here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/transactions.html

Comment: So I should do my return before or after the transaction commit ?

Comment: After tx.commit(). If this fails you don't even get to return because RuntimeException is thrown on which you do rollback, since committing failed. On rollback normally you should throw another business exception or exactly the same cached exception but is important that data is not returned.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is not catched and I still have the same error.

Comment: It seems that in debug mode, the return correctly returns my pictures, with its user and category attached. But it crash when debugger is doing things out of my code...

Comment: Maybe you have in your debugger a spy which loads your lazy collection during the session?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate the `OneToMany` properties `user.pictures` and `category.pictures` with the fetch strategy `EAGER`.

```
class Category {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Collection<Picture> pictures;
}

class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Collection<Picture> pictures;
}
```

As a side note, you actually don't need to decorate the `ManyToOne` properties with the `EAGER` fetch strategy as this is considered *the default behavior*.

Comment: I have already tried this, but it throw me an error telling that an infinite xml file will be procude with this : com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.Picture@53de7f5 -> com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.User@8f5a795 -> com.supinfo.suppicture.entity.Picture@53de7f5]